# Change target framework ClickOnce Deployment

Tags: .net, frameworks, clickonce

I have a windows utility tool which is targeted to .Net Framework 4.5 in Visual Studio and I published it using ClickOnce. So if anyone tries to download and run the tool, it expects the client's machines' to have 4.5 Framework installed on their machine. However I don't want to force all the clients to upgrade their machines to 4.5 instead I want to change the target framework while publishing the tool. So is there a way to change only the deployment target framework as I don't want to change the VS project.

I tried to change the config file to set the 4.0 framework but when I run the tool it shows signature mismatch error. As the config file will be modified upon every time we build the project, I am thinking we should somehow set the target framework as part of the TFS build project itself. My current TFS Build.proj shows as

```
<MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionRoot)\Client\Windows\Utility Tool\Utility Tool.csproj"     
Targets="Build;Publish;Package"  
Properties="Configuration=Release;BuildEnvironment=.QA;WarningsNotAsErrors=618,168;
ApplicationVersion=$(CurrentAssemblyVersionText);
PublishURL=https://mycompany.com/myeut/"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running out of luck with IE9 and later. Before, Http request carried .Net framework installation within its hierarchies of properties. But with IE9 Microsoft standardized information in the property `UserAgent` [I think]. Because IE didn't comply to some browsers rules and other browsers did - they didn't include that information.

What you can "try to do" is to create `ClickOnce` loader program in FW 2.0, which will run, check the machine for frameworks installed. And I am not even sure that this will work because you have very limited access to machine in ClickOnce deployment, you are in Internet sandbox. But if that is possible, your Loader can download right application cache and start the application.

Believe it or not, I worked on project like this, but after IE9, we just put .Net framework prerequisite into product guide.